# Нужно вытянуть с mssql картинки и сохранить на диск

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, изображения

Нашел на просторах интернета это решение: [ссылка на stackoverflow][1]

но не получается его применить в моем случае, сам код:

```
import sys, os, pyodbc, io
from  PIL import Image

def m1():
    data = ""
    server = 'ip'
    database = 'base'
    username = 'login'
    password = 'pw'
    driver = '{SQL Server}'  # Driver you need to connect to the database
    cnn = pyodbc.connect(
        'DRIVER=' + driver + ';PORT=port;SERVER=' + server + ';PORT=1443;DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username +
        ';PWD=' + password)
    cursor = cnn.cursor()


  date = cursor.execute("""select top 150 e.ENTID,ENTTYPE,id.filename,id.type,d.DATA from ATTACHHD id
                    join ATTACHDATA d on d.ATTACHKEY=id.ATTACHKEY1
                    join ENTITY e on e.ATTACHID=id.ATTACHID
```

""")
    cnt = 0
    data = tuple()
    for row in date:
        #print(type(row[:4]))
        data += row[4:]
        cnt +=1
        print(cnt)
    print(type(data))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

```
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(data))
# image.save("./1qwe.png")

# print(io.BytesIO(row.DATA).read(10))
```

m1()

```
сам Traceback: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pythonsql/test2.py", line 37, in <module>
    m1()
  File "C:/pythonsql/test2.py", line 33, in m1
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(data))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'

[![скриншот][2]][2]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203413/python-pyodbc-retrieving-images-from-mssql-data-how-to
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezavh.png
```

Comment: Написано же `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'pyodbc.Row'`. В чем проблема? :) Вам нужно ответить на следующие вопросы: какие значения хранятся в `DATA`? Как из `i` получить значение `DATA`?

Comment: cursor.execute("select DATA from ATTACHDATA where _OID=521177")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print(type(row.DATA))
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(row.DATA))
    image.save("./qwe.jpg")

Спасибо, но теперь Traceback:
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001F29E7E12B0>

Comment: А выведите плиз в консоль: `print(row.DATA[:100])` если не выйдет, то `print(row.DATA)`. Вы не ответили какое значение в `DATA` если там байты, то это одно дело, то там скорее всего строка в Base64. Вывод в консоль поможет понять что в DATA :) Еще можно попробовать: `print(io.BytesIO(row.DATA).read())` и `print(io.BytesIO(row.DATA).read(100))`

Comment: b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe1E\xfeExif\x00\x00II*\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x0e\x01\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x92\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x01\x02\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\xb2\x00\x00\x00\x10\x01\x02\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x12\x01\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x1a\x01\x05\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xce\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x01\x05\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xd6\x00\x00\x00(\x01\x03\x00\x01\x00'

Comment: Простите, меня дизинформировали. скорее всего, это не картинка вовсе. может быть pdf или doc... Я отпишусь позже

Comment: Попробуйте: `with open('img.jpg', 'wb') as f:` `f.write(row.DATA)` Но это может не помочь, т.к. хоть там у вас файл, это не обязательно картинка (хотя `Exif` говорит что возможно она) :) Если вы не знаете что там, то в поле таблицы нужно сохранять формат файла. И даже если у вас там не картинка, то можете также через `open` записывать файл, только уточните его формат

Comment: Как оказалось файл состоит из множества даты...(не знаю правильно ли я выразился), сейчас поправлю вопрос и добавлю скриншот что бы было ясно. как ее сконтактировать ? попробывал сложить в tuple все но получаю Traceback